# Azure Function + Javascript how to get the data I pass in the post request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, azure-functions

I have an Azure function written in Javascript.

the functions takes as a parameter the context and the request as follows:

```
function(context, req)
```

It's pretty easy to retrieve anything passed through a GET request **by using the req object**, if for example I pass name=test in the URL I can retrieve it in my code as follows:

```
var myVar = req.query.name
```

Anyhow, when it happens that the verb is not a GET but a POST (and as a consequence the data are passed in the body and not as param in the URL), I don't know the way to retrieve the data.

The official documentation did not help me to understand this specific context, although it should be a silly thing.

**How can I populate the variable myVar if the key "name" is passed in the body?**

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

If you POST to the Azure Function you can use require('querystring') https://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html

For example if you have an HTML page with a form with POST action e.g.:

````
```
<form action="..../api/{your_azure_function}">
First name:<br>
<input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey">
<br>
Last name:<br>
<input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse">
<br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 
```
````

Your azure function(Nodejs) will need to:
    
    `/* Require for Post */
    const querystring = require('querystring');`

Then you can access the body with:
    
    `var user_input = querystring.parse(req.body);
    firstn1 = user_input.firstname //contains Mickey
    lastn = user_input.lastname    //contains Mouse`

Answer (score 1):

I believe you would want to use context.req.body to get the request body. You can parse the body and get your name attribute.

See if this is useful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node#http-triggers-and-bindings

Comment: Also see the JavaScript example in the [HttpTrigger binding reference.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook#trigger---javascript-example). The bodies of `application/json` or `application/octet-stream`-headered requests [will be parsed for you.](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/blob/ec8984ef1529c95aa5638c5c942eb55077d95b4b/src/WebJobs.Script/Rpc/MessageExtensions/RpcMessageConversionExtensions.cs#L110-L135)